# The "historical significance" post notice has some broken formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, post-notices

Currently, the historical significance notice (as seen on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), for example), looks slightly off. Probably a bit of Markdown gone wrong:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, [...]. More info: **[FAQ](/faq)(/faq)**.

Other notices with links, such as "insufficient explanation", don't seem to be affected.

Comment: Probably because of the change to use restricted comment formatting. In comments, `[FAQ]` is already auto-expanded, therefore no need for an additional `(/faq)` link.

Comment: Weird how it says "question" when it is under an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated post notice will be rolled out with the next build.